# How to end the turtle loop in Python while executing from Anaconda?

Tags: python, while-loop, anaconda, turtle-graphics

I have the below code: The loop does not end and the turtle keeps making circle.

```
    import turtle
    from turtle import Turtle
    from random import randint
    window=turtle.Screen()
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    #circle
    t.reset()
    while True:
        t.forward(2)
        t.right(1)
    if abs(pos()) < 1:
        break
```

I am executing this from Jupyter notebook. The same code works well if i execute from command prompt.
 Please advise!!

Thanks

Comment: @davedwards: And i do that. I have that If loop inside it that would break the out of the loop. Remember, this same code works well when executed from command prompt.

Comment: yes I agree, because I was wrong I deleted my comment

Comment: You've got an indentation mistake: The `if` needs to be inside the `while` loop, not after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't work at the command prompt as written, despite you saying it does (twice.)  The problem is the `pos()` call -- it throws `NameError: name 'pos' is not defined`.  If you had also thrown in an `from turtle import *` among your multiple turtle imports, then it would run, but incorrectly as you would be moving *your* turtle `t`, but testing the *default* turtle's position.  In this simplified form it should work:

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()

while True:
    t.forward(2)
    t.right(1)
    if abs(t.pos()) < 1:
        break

turtle.done()
```